# Getting bug with rvm ruby versions

Tags: ruby, rvm, gemfile

I'm getting the following bug when I run `rails c`:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2
```

When I run `$rvm list rubies`, I get the following:

```
rvm rubies
=* ruby-2.2.2 [ x86_64 ]
```

I am confused. I tried to change the Ruby version in the Gemfile to 2.1.2 and install ruby-2.1.2. However I still get:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.2.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `$ ruby -v` return?

Comment: ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 2):

Please install ruby-2.2.2 on your system then do either one of these:

```
1. rvm use ruby-2.2.2
2. create a .ruby-version file inside your application root folder with the following content:
   2.2.2
```

Comment: I would rather create a .ruby-version file with "ruby-2.2.2"

Comment: I'm already have installed ruby-2.2.2 and i tried to reinstall it and ruby-2.1.2

Comment: Did you used the desired ruby version you need?

Comment: I used 2.2.1 before, but today project ruby version has changed to 2.2.2, after i installed it this bug began to appear

Comment: @AmitBadhekaPykihStaff is mostly right.  `.rvmrc` is deprecated - you should use `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset`, but you only need to write `2.2.2` in the `.ruby-version`.  unrelated, but 2.2.2 has a few bugs, I'd recommend using 2.1.6 for the moment

Comment: yes correct instead .rvmrc you can have a .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ rm Gemfile.lock
$ bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither answer worked for me, and I already had 2.2.2 installed and specified in .ruby-version. What worked for me was

```
rvm use 2.1.2
rvm use 2.2.2
```

and then everything works fine. I suspect that rvm was somehow confused.

Declaration: In reality, I had this problem with swapping between 2.5.9 and 2.7.3.